# Vim multiline search using Negative lookahead

Tags: vim

I was trying to search the following pattern in a log.

```
[write_<many other characters here till end of line>
<10-15 lines here>
<more characters> 10008
```

My log has many such occurrences with the last value not being 10008. 
First I tried searching this like this :

```
/\[write_\_.\{-}10008
```

This was matching [write_ from some lines much ahead of the nearest [write_ to 10008. This is why tried to filter out such bogus matches using negative lookahead.

```
/\[write_\_.\{-}10008\([write_\)\@!
```

This also didn't work for me. Where did I go wrong, or am I thinking in completely wrong direction? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
/\v\[write_(\_.(\[write_)@!){-}10008
```

You put the negative look ahead in wrong place.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this but getting "E363: pattern uses more memory than 'maxmempattern'
Interrupted". I don't understand what this means. Can you please help in setting this value appropriately.

Comment: If you get the `E363` error with Kent's pattern, then your file may contain big parts (something more than ~1000 lines) without any `[write_` header, i guess; (I was looking to correct it, but sorry I can't find the right pattern..)

Comment: @thorondor1990 I tested with some examples, it worked. but how does your real file look like I don't know. if you had `E363`, pls try `:set maxmempattern=A_BIG_NUMBER`

Comment: Tried this after setting maxmempattern to 1000000. gvim got hung for about 15 mins after executing the command, later came up with same error. Probably due to the huge size of the log and large number of lines to cover between 2 [write_ patterns. Anyways, I checked with a smaller example and @Kent 's solution is indeed working. Thanks Kent and yolenoyer

Comment: @thorondor1990 I don't know what do you want to do with those match, just a tip, you can search 10008 first, and backwards look for `[write` to locate the block, then do whatever on the block. you can do it with macro.

Comment: @Kent I was searching for AHB transactions with address 10008 in a log generated after a simulation. There are many transactions with different addresses and I wanted to filter out those with 10008. Luckily I had another source (waveform) from which I could extract timestamp of the transaction and corner my manual search in log. So all good. But I was trying to do this without help of waveform.